# submit form AFTER captcha validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the snippet of my code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").mouseup(function(){
    if(grecaptcha.getResponse().length > 0) {
      $('form').submit();
      $('.container').html('thanks bye!');
    }
  });
});
```

When running this, it submits the form even if `grecaptcha.getResponse().length > 0` is False.

Why?

Comment: did you debug your code ? is it `grecaptcha.getResponse().length` actually 0 ?

Comment: What does you `#button` do? Maybe you do not prevent form submittion? Show HTML too

Comment: @Rahul yes the if statement returns false

Comment: it seems to me somewhat event issue `mouseup` not sure though...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").mouseup(function(e){
    if(grecaptcha.getResponse().length > 0) {
      $('form').submit();
      $('.container').html('thanks bye!');
    }else{
        e.preventDefault();
    }
  });

  $("#button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent submission of form will be using `javascript` `onclick` like below

```js
/*You dont need this javascript function*/
var odd=false;
var grecaptcha={
  getResponse:function(){
  odd=!odd;
  if(!odd) return "";
  return "You don't need this function";
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Submit On Alternate Click" onclick="if(grecaptcha.getResponse().length > 0) return false; alert('This is even Time So form fill submit')"/>
```

Comment: Can you explain `You can't use event.preventDefault() in jQuery`?

Answer (score -1):

try this `if(grecaptcha.getResponse().length != 0)` instead!

Comment: Why it should change anything? If length is `5`, so `5 > 0 === 5 != 0`